# React Switch not rendering different pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a react app that got a component that renders my HomePage. I decided to create another component so i can switch between pages on the site. For the HomePage it works when i enter the site, but clicking on navlinks is not working, also if i type the url /contacto i am not getting the render of Contact component, i get the render of the HomePage component, it's not switching between them.

```
class ContactPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>HOLA</div>;
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/contacto" component={ContactPage} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try changing `<Route path="/"` to `<Route exact path="/"`

Comment: @cubrr it works perfect now! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `exact` to your `HomePage` route:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
```

This is because the path `/` still matches in a non exact way to `/contacto` and the router renders the first match (that being your HomePage).

By adding `exact`, you're telling it not to match partial matches.